# Mixed-design anova for unbalanced group size with two within-subjects factors in R

Tags: r, unbalanced-classes, anova

I have a set of data for 44 subjects who are categorized into 3 different groups of High, Mid and Low hypnotizability (High group: 7 subjects, Mid group: 28 subjects, Low group: 9 subjects).

For each subject I have measured brain activities (mean Theta power) in 14 locations (scalp electrodes) and in 14 different time segments. 
So now I want to see if there is a significant effect of hypnotizability (High vs Mid vs Low), electrode location (CH1~CH14), and time segments (which are the experiment phases of Pre, Ind, ... Awake, Post) in Theta power changes.

My data is sorted in long format with four factors and one response as:

```
'Sub'    'Hypno'     'Locati'     'Segmnt'  'ThetaPower'

Sub1     High    CH1     Pre    0.71617

Sub1     High    CH1     Ind    0.53548

Sub1     High    CH1     Sug1   0.60792

Sub1     High    CH1     Sug2   0.60126

Sub1     High    CH1     Sug3   0.91526

Sub1     High    CH1     Sug4   0.84837

Sub1     High    CH1     Sug5   0.27119

Sub1     High    CH1     Sug6   -0.31119

Sub1     High    CH1     Sug7   1.1648

Sub1     High    CH1     Sug8   0.74608

Sub1     High    CH1     Sug9   0.4283

Sub1     High    CH1     Sug10  0.49491

Sub1     High    CH1     Awake  1.1598

Sub1     High    CH1     Post   0.37392

--------------------
Sub1     High    CH2     Pre    2.586

Sub1     High    CH2     Ind    2.9232

.
.
.

---------
.
.
.
.

Sub3     Mid     CH1     Pre    3.7453

Sub3     Mid     CH1     Ind    2.8817

Sub3     Mid     CH1     Sug1   3.4654

Sub3     Mid     CH1     Sug2   3.6996

Sub3     Mid     CH1     Sug3   3.9869

.
.
.

---------
.
.
.

Sub46    Low     CH14    Sug9   11.073

Sub46    Low     CH14    Sug10  10.959

Sub46    Low     CH14    Awake  11.079

Sub46    Low     CH14    Post   8.2441
```

I assume I need a mixed-design anova with repeated measures: 
3(Hypnotizability) * 14 (electrode locations) * 14 (time segments). 
among these variables Hypnotizability is a between-subject and the other two (locations and time segments) are within-subjects variables.

1. Can anybody help me how to fit a model?  Is the following right? or
   shall I use another function such as lmer?

   `fit <- aov( ThetaPower ~ Hypnotizibility * Location * Segment +
   Error(Subject/(Location*Segment)), data = Data)`
2. What post-hoc test can be used?